# AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'cleaner'

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, scikit-learn, joblib

We are creating web-site with ai assistant. We trained our model in Google Colab and now we are trying to upload it to our project. But we get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'cleaner'
```

In our file `views.py` declared the class `VoiceAssistant` and the function `cleaner` for pipeline. The problem is hidden on the line:

```
talk_model = joblib.load(r'artifitial_assistant/model.pkl')
```

While training our model we used the following code:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('bow',
                 CountVectorizer(analyzer = cleaner)),
                ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier())])
```

Views.py:

```
import string
import traceback
import webbrowser
import joblib
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition
import wikipedia
from django.shortcut import render


def cleaner(x):
    """
    cleaning function required for neural model
    """
    return [a for a in (''.join([a for a in x if a not in string.punctuation])).lower().split()]


class VoiceAssistant:
    """
    Settings of our voice assistant
    """
    name = ""
    sex = ""
    speech_lang = ""
    is_talking = False
    recognition_lang = ""
    # initializing speech recognition and input tools
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()

    # initialization of the speech synthesis tool
    ttsEngine = pyttsx3.init()

    def assistant_answer(self, voice):
        """
        a function that loads user input into the neural model and predicts the response
        """
        answer = self.talk_model.predict([voice])[0]
        return answer


    # loading a neural model from disk
    talk_model = joblib.load(r'artifitial_assistant/model.pkl') # !!!<-Problem uppears here
    
    ... 

    
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

#initializing voice_assistant
voice_assistant = VoiceAssistant()
voice_assistant.sex = "female"
voice_assistant.speech_lang = "en"
voice_assistant.name = "blonde"
voice_assistant.setup_assistant_voice()


def first_view(request): #just want to get the simplest response from voice_assistant
    return HttpResponse(voice_assistant.assistant_answer('Hi'))
```

Comment: How are you importing `cleaner` from `views.py`, and where is the file with `Pipeline` located?

Comment: 1) Pipeline is method for machine learning, we don't use it now. It was important for training our model. So, we don't use this part of code now. 2)We don't import cleaner function to anywhere in our code. This is django. This method is required by our model(ai) to be there. We don't explicitly call this method

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I just added *cleaner* function to the manage.py, because there is the module ***main***. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of your module from "main" to anything else, and it should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).